# The bot does not respond to the message

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

I started to learn about discord.js but now I'm facing this problem. I tried some intents but I couldn't fix it.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: 3276799 });
const config = require("./config.json");

  client.on("message", async message => {
  
      if(message.author.bot) return;
      if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;
      if(!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
  
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const comando = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    // comando ping
    if(comando === "ping") {
      const m = await message.channel.send("Ping?");
      m.edit(`Pong! A Latência é ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms. A Latencia da API é ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`);
    }
  
  client.login(config.token);
```

Comment: it should be 'messageCreate'

Answer (score 0):

There are missing closing parenthesis for `client.on` hook, so your code should look like:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: 3276799 });
const config = require("./config.json");

client.on("message", async message => {

    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;
    if(!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const comando = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
  // comando ping
  if(comando === "ping") {
    const m = await message.channel.send("Ping?");
    m.edit(`Pong! A Latência é ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms. A Latencia da API é ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`);
  }
})

client.login(config.token);
```